# How to understand this C declaration code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded-linux

When seeing some piece of codes I saw this "declaration" - as far as I can understand this is a declaration - at [/drivers/base/cpu.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.33/source/drivers/base/cpu.c#L91) in the kernel:

```
static CLASS_ATTR(probe, S_IWUSR, NULL, cpu_probe_store);
```

The file is written in C/C++ is cpu.c but with my limited knowledge of C/C++ I have no idea what the meaning of this "declaration" line. No need to explain about the actual meaning of parameters in this file, if possible just show me the role definition of this "declaration".

Comment: *but with my limited knowledge of C/C++*, every person you meet here will have limited to no knowledge of C/C++ because the language doesn't exist. It is either C or C++.

Comment: but I guess, @AjayBrahmakshatriya we should start teaching people about `c/c++`, just to stay away from it, because, it' UB. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh it would be nice to have a book with the title "Guide to using C/C++" and inside it the first page just says - It doesn't exist. End. :)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - [According to Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#C-is-subset): *"C++ is as much a superset of ANSI C as ANSI C is a superset of K&R C and much as ISO C++ is a superset of C++ as it existed in 1985"* and *"Well written C tends to be legal C++ also"*. I doubt you will find anyone who can write C++ but not C.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - *"...  it would be nice to have a book ... and inside it the first page just says It doesn't exist"* - Unfortunately, it does not exist. In fact, the opposite is true. See the preface of Stroustrup's *[The C++ Programming Language](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321563840)*.

Comment: @jww *"Well written C tends to be legal C++ also"* is questionable. I am sure you must be aware of certain differences in the standard. (pointer assignability, ++ returning lvlaue etc). And even if certain code behaves the same in C or C++ it should still not be called C/C++ because the standards can change and they are not bound to behave the same for that code. A code is in the language it's author intended to write it for.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - Forgive my ignorance... Where does C/C++ mean one language? I've been working with both for about 20 years, and I read it as "the C and C++ family of languages" (re: C++ is mostly a superset of C). Its been that way since I was in college. I'll even toss Objective C in on occasion when it applies with no material difference. When did folks start reading it as a single language?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, jww thank you both for the comments. I just want to express that I'm just a beginner, and I write C/C++ means [C or C++] (since they have many similarities), NOT a programming language called C/C++.

Comment: @jww that is all I was saying. The author of the question mentioned - "The file is written in C/C++". I was just pointing out that such a language doesn't exist. I corrected him because he also tagged both the languages. Maybe for this question it doesn't matter because the answer will be the same w.r.t. both the languages but it is bad practice. I am okay with the statement that C is very similar to a subset of C++ (pardon me if my comments gave a hint against it), I was just trying to say that C/C++ doesn't exist.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - I think this fellow's use of tags is correct. I considered how to edit them, and I can't drop C or C++ without detracting from some of the finer issues or points. For example, `cpu.c` seems to be a C file. It appears to be using C defines like `S_IWUSR`. Then it uses a C++ concept of a class with the macro `CLASS_ATTR`. OP admits he's not an expert; he seemed to tag according to the way a that's expected due to the confusion.

Comment: @jww Okay, I agree with you. The confusion in this case is warranted because of the naming.

Comment: With the partial info you publish it is impossible to guess anything.  You ask for C declaration but the one posted is more a C++ declaration with an initializator.  You mess without any order C and C++, as if both languages where the same.  As no definition of what `CLASS_ATTR` is, there's no possibility of going further.  Please, edit and include the definition of `CLASS_ATTR` and better, **read about how to post a question in SO**.

Comment: @LuisColorado: I found what I need and even more through the comments of jww and Ajay Brahmakshatriya and I accepted the answer already. Anyway, thanks for the comment, next time I'll consider more when posting a question.

Comment: @LêQuangDuy, even in that case, you need to know how to ask a question in stackoverflow, as you are not the only man in the world who needs an answer on that subject.  You make our work more difficult, you have to read more to get your problem solved, and the answer only works for you, and not for other people.  Anyway, as you say, your problem is solved, and I must shut up now. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly `CLASS_ATTR` is a macro. These macros is well linked to its definition in the website you post. Just click the name, following the search result, especially in header files you'll find the definition.

[CLASS_ATTR](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.33/source/include/linux/device.h#L258)

[__ATTR](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.33/source/include/linux/sysfs.h#L48)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Better to provide definitions in place in answer. Links might gone.